# Make a comma separated list of out of co-ordinates from a csv file

Tags: python-2.7

I have values x and y in a csv and i am reading those values and converting them into a numpy array using below code:

```
import numpy as np
import csv
data = np.loadtxt('datapoints.csv', delimiter=',')

# Putting data from csv file to variable
x = data[:, 0]
y = data[:, 1]

# Converting npArray to simple array
np.asarray(x)
np.asarray(y)
```

So, now i have the values of x and y. 
But, i want them to be in this format:

```
[[x1,y1],[x2,y2], [x3,y3], ...... [xn,yn]]
```

How do i do that?

Comment: Why don't you take slice of `data` directly, like `data[:, 0:2]`? You can use `.tolist()` method then if you really want a list of lists.

Comment: Why not just `zip(np.asarray(x), np.asarray(y))`?

Comment: To be honest, I didn't know i could do that. I am new to python. I just tried that, but it is not separated by comma

Comment: yeah using `zip(np.asarray(x), np.asarray(y))` gives me comma separated values. But, it is of the format, `[(x1,y1),(x2,y2), (x3,y3), ...... (xn,yn)]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use zip :

```
result = [list(a) for a in zip(np.asarray(x),np.asarray(y))]
```

Comment: modified the answer:)